# Get settings from appsettings.json using the percentage syntax

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core

If you want a ServiceBusTrigger to use a setting from de appsettings.json, you can do this like this:

```
[ServiceBusTrigger("%CommandQueue:QueueName%")]
```

But what if I have an array of queues in my appsettings and I want to point a one of those.

```
{
   "Queues": [
      {
          "QueueName": "ThisOne",
          "EndPoint": "TheEndMyFriend"
      }
]}
```

I want to specify something like this:

```
[ServiceBusTrigger("%CommandQueue:Queues{QueueName=ThisOne}:EndPoint%")]
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. That's not possible. As it currently stands, the best you can do is an index, since this is an array. In other words, if you knew that the one you wanted to use from the array was the second item, for example, then you could use `%CommandQueue:Queues:1:Endpoint%`. However, that's pretty fragile, as if you change the order, insert a new queue before it, etc., then your code would break.

If you changed the format of your config to an object of objects:

```
"Queues": {
    "ThisOne": {
        "EndPoint": "TheEndMyFriend"
    }
}
```

Then, you could use `%CommandQueue:Queues:ThisOne:EndPoint%`, which would be more robust.